# Y-axis labels are not displaying properly

Tags: r, rcharts

I have created following dummy rCharts:

```
My_Data <- data.frame(Names = sapply(1:26, function(x) return(paste(sample(letters, 26), collapse = ""))), Att1 = LETTERS, Number = 1:26)
    n1 <- nPlot(Number ~ Names, group = "Att1", data = My_Data, type = "multiBarHorizontalChart")
    n1$params$height = 5000
    n1$params$width  = 1000
    n1
```

However when this plot is displayed in browser, the names in the Y-axis are not visible clearly. Those names are lengthy by how they have been created in my original requirement. Can someone point me how to display the full names?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

Setting the margins should help.  Maybe something like

```
n1$chart(margin=list(top= 30, right= 20, bottom= 50, left= 250))
```